# move file name with unique id from new folder to SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've looked around and haven't found particularly what I'm after.
I have quite a few forms with text input and file uploads.

I've figured how to upload a file, give it a unique ID and get it into my web server folder. Pretty smooth sailing. However, I would like to also get that fancy new ID into my MySQL database.

I've separated my upload.php page with text forms going to the database

```
<?php

//Connecting and Sending data to the database follows
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'surfboardhub')
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server');

//Get values from  
$location = "";
$price = "";
$thick = "";
$width = "";
$height ="";
$model = "";
$brand = "";
$email = "";
$category = "";

if(isset($_POST['location'])){ $location = $_POST['location']; }
if(isset($_POST['price'])){ $price = $_POST['price']; }
if(isset($_POST['thick'])){ $thick = $_POST['thick']; }
if(isset($_POST['width'])){ $width = $_POST['width']; }
if(isset($_POST['height'])){ $height = $_POST['height']; }
if(isset($_POST['model'])){ $model = $_POST['model']; }
if(isset($_POST['brand'])){ $brand = $_POST['brand']; }
if(isset($_POST['email'])){ $email = $_POST['email']; }

//if(isset($_POST['image'])){ $imagename = $_POST['imagename']; } 
//if(isset($_POST['mime'])){ $mime = $_POST['mime']; } 

$query = "INSERT INTO uploads (location, price, thick, width, height, model, brand, email,category) 
VALUES ('$location', '$price','$thick','$width','$height', '$model', '$brand', '$email','$category')";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query)
or die('Error querying database.');

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

and then my bit to get the file to its new location in my web server.

```
$name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$extension = strtolower(substr($name, strpos($name, '.') + 1));
$type = $_FILES['image']['type'];

$tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if (isset($name)) {
if (!empty($name)) {
if (($extension=='jpg'||$extension=='jpeg'||$extension=='png'||$extension=="gif")&&$type=='image/jpeg'||$type=='image/png'||$type=='image/gif') {


 $location = 'uploads/';
 $location = $location . uniqid();



   if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)) {
  echo 'uploaded!';
    } 

    else {
   echo 'There was an error.';
    }


} else {
echo 'File must be jpg/jpeg, png, or gif.';
}

} else {
echo 'Please choose a file';
}
}
?>
```

Basically, I need to get that new unique ID to go to where the text information is going, because they're all being submitted at once. And I'd like to be able to figure out who uploaded what if need be. If it didn't have a unique ID I can get it to work, but for some reason having that uniqid trips me up. Thoughts? Much obliged.

Comment: `uniqid()` should be assigned to/concatenated to the filename, not the folder.

Comment: so the file's name is 'image'. you don't mean $location = $image . uniqid(); ? and then writing that value up top? I don't think I follow.

Comment: I tried, $location = $name . uniqid();  and it sends the image outside of the folder.

Comment: Try `$random = $name . "_" . uniqid(); $location = 'uploads/'; if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$random)){...}`

Comment: you are my hero. it totally worked! At first I erroneously entered $ID = ""; like the rest in the //get values from forms in the column up top, but once I got rid of that it worked like a charm. stoked! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You're umm... welcome. You should've asked me to put in an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the `uniqid()` to a PHP variable and then you can use it in more than one place:

First, create an ID:

```
<?php
    $ID = uniqid();
?>
```

Then, save your file, using your new `$ID` variable:

```
<?php
    $name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $extension = strtolower(substr($name, strpos($name, '.') + 1));
    $type = $_FILES['image']['type'];

    $tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    if (isset($name)) {
        if (!empty($name)) {
            if (($extension=='jpg'||$extension=='jpeg'||$extension=='png'||$extension=="gif")&&$type=='image/jpeg'||$type=='image/png'||$type=='image/gif') {
                $location = 'uploads/';
                $location = $location . $ID;

                if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)) {
                    echo 'uploaded!';
                } else {
                    echo 'There was an error.';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'File must be jpg/jpeg, png, or gif.';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Please choose a file';
        }
    }
?>
```

Then, save your data to the db, including $ID

```
<?php
    //Connecting and Sending data to the database follows
    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'surfboardhub')
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server');

    //Get values from  
    $location = "";
    $price = "";
    $thick = "";
    $width = "";
    $height ="";
    $model = "";
    $brand = "";
    $email = "";
    $category = "";

    if(isset($_POST['location'])){ $location = $_POST['location']; }
    if(isset($_POST['price'])){ $price = $_POST['price']; }
    if(isset($_POST['thick'])){ $thick = $_POST['thick']; }
    if(isset($_POST['width'])){ $width = $_POST['width']; }
    if(isset($_POST['height'])){ $height = $_POST['height']; }
    if(isset($_POST['model'])){ $model = $_POST['model']; }
    if(isset($_POST['brand'])){ $brand = $_POST['brand']; }
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){ $email = $_POST['email']; }

    //if(isset($_POST['image'])){ $imagename = $_POST['imagename']; } 
    //if(isset($_POST['mime'])){ $mime = $_POST['mime']; } 

    $query = "INSERT INTO uploads (ID, location, price, thick, width, height, model, brand, email,category) 
    VALUES ('$ID', '$location', '$price','$thick','$width','$height', '$model', '$brand', '$email','$category')";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query)
    or die('Error querying database.');

    mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```